# javascript validation of a variable sequence of letters and numbers from a text input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a number of different companies (customers) in a DB. Each one requires an order number to be passed to them. But they all want the order number to be a different sequence of numbers and letters.

So in the DB I have a column which represents this format. e.g.
`@@@###@@@ => 3 letters, 3 numbers, 3 letters`
`AB##@@ => 'AB', 2 numbers, 2 letters`
`###### => 6 numbers`
etc.

I need to validate user input (to a text box) of these order numbers so they comply with the customer's requirements regarding string structure.

Any ideas how I could achieve this with javascript? Is there a function or library I could use that I could simply 'plug-in' the format taken from the DB and it would return true or false based on the characters the user has inputted.

A 'fixed' regex is easy enough, but this is dynamic and based on the customer and there are hundreds of different formats...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Quiet loose, `^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$`.

Comment: But I need an exact replica of the order number structure per customer. So one might be @@@## (letter, letter, letter, number, number) and another might be AA#### (starts with AA followed by 4 numbers). There are hundreds of different formats in this DB.

Comment: What I need is some kind of library that will take the format from the DB, interpret it as 'constants', letters, numbers and then return true or false. Or something similar...

Comment: _"A 'fixed' regex is easy enough, but this is dynamic and based on the customer and there are hundreds of different formats..."_ How is the specific customer determined at user input ?

Comment: It is on page load. The more I think about it the more ways I can think of possibly implementing a solution but I think phenxd has given me the most concise solution of simply building up the regex with string replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @ -> letter and #  -> number are your only special cases, you could simply do a replace into a regex.

```
var formatField = "AB##@#YZ";
formatField = formatField.split('@').join('[a-zA-Z]');
formatField = formatField.split('#').join('[0-9]');

var reg = new RegExp("^" + formatField + "$");
console.log(reg.test("AB12R3YZ")); // true
console.log(reg.test("2312R3YZ")); // false
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vcmo8ds/6/#&togetherjs=kdQE8Ged6T)

Comment: ahhh, I see, you are replacing the @ symbols with [a-zA-Z] and you are replacing the # symbols with [0-9] thus building up the regex :) Very nice solution. Thank you phenxd :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `select` element for users to choose which company they will be inputting customer numbers for; at selection you could display the `input` element associated with that company having a `pattern` attribute that contains the `RegExp` reflecting that company's required input